# Using grep to find user names

Tags: bash

I have a log file that has thousands of user login attempts, and I need to find the login attempts that failed and list the usernames of the failed attempts.

The failed attempts are all marked with "input_userauth_request". So I started by using:

grep "input_userauth_request" file.txt which listed all of the lines that look like this:

userauth_request: invalid user nagios [preauth]

userauth_request: invalid user student [preauth]

userauth_request: invalid user sales [preauth]

Now I need to list the user names and I can't figure out how to print just those user names. So basically I need to figure out how to print:

nagios

student

sales

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: None of your 3 lines contain `input_userauth_request`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize it cut it off when I copied it. They should read: input_userauth_request: invalid user nagios [preauth]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this as the test file:

```
$ cat file.txt
userauth_request: invalid user nagios [preauth]
userauth_request: invalid user student [preauth]
userauth_request: invalid user sales [preauth]
```

This awk command retrieves the user names:

```
$ awk '/userauth_request/ {print $4}' file.txt
nagios
student
sales
```

#### How it works

- `/userauth_request/`

  This selects lines which match the regex userauth_request`
- `print $4`

  For the lines selected, this prints the fourth field.

#### Improvements

If file.txt is large, there will likely be duplicate names.  If you want to remove duplicate names:

```
$ awk '/userauth_request/ {print $4}' file.txt | sort -u
nagios
sales
student
```

If instead you would like a count of how many times each student tried unsuccessfully to log in:

```
$ awk '/userauth_request/ {print $4}' file.txt | sort | uniq -c
      1 nagios
      1 sales
      1 student
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pipe to `cut` to get the `name` field, to `grep .` to discard empty lines and to `sort -u` to get unique results:

```
grep "userauth_request" file.txt | cut -d' ' -f4 | grep . | sort -u
```

You will get:

```
nagios
sales
student
```

Answer (score 0):

If your grep has Perl Regex Support (PCRE) like gnu grep 3.1 then you can do something like:

```
$ cat file1
userauth_request: invalid user nagios [preauth]
userauth: succesful user george [auth]
userauth_request: invalid user student [preauth]
userauth_request: invalid user sales [preauth]

$ grep -Po 'userauth_request:.*user \K.[^[]*' file1
nagios 
student 
sales
```

`-P` enables PCRE
`-o` returns matched pattern only instead of the whole line (grep default)
`\K` means forget everything so far and look forward
`.[^[]*` means capture all chars up to first found `[` (excluding this `[` char)